# Specifying a blank argument in symfony service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to define a custom SwiftMailer Transport in symfony as a service and nearly got it, apart from the service definition. The XML below is from the Swiftmailer-Mailgun-bundle and this works, however all the config in our app is in YML, what would be the YAML version of the XML below?

```
<service id="mailgun.swift_transport.transport" class="cspoo\Swiftmailer\MailgunBundle\Service\MailgunTransport" public="true">
    <argument></argument>
    <argument type="service" id="mailgun.library"></argument>
    <argument>%mailgun.domain%</argument>
</service>
```

Its the  bit, I don't know how you do this in YAML.

Comment: If you look at the many examples in the docs you will see a tab that lets you flip between xml and yml.  Should not be hard to figure out.  I could try an answer but without testing there is a significant chance of small syntax errors.

Comment: The value in YAML is either `""` or `~`, depending on whether you want an empty string or null.

Comment: Yeah, symfony then moans saying the argument should be an instance of Swift_Events_EventDispatcher. What I need to tell Symfony is that the parameter should be of that type, but I've only ever passed other symfony things to services, i.e. parameters, services (logger, doctrine, containers etc..)

Comment: I even tried setting the parameter to '@swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher', but that just gave a service not found error ... eg ...

swiftmailer.mailer.transport.mailgun:
              class: foo\WebsiteBundle\SwiftMailer\customMailgunTransport
              arguments: ['@swiftmailer.transport.eventdispatcher','@mailgun.library','testdomain.com']

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out myself. Looking at the code in the mailgun bundle, it has a class called cspooSwiftmailerMailgunExtension which decorates the service definition, defining this blank argument defined in the XML to be a type of mailgun.swift_transport.eventdispatcher, so sure enough, adding that into the config appears to have fixed it.

```
swiftmailer.mailer.transport.engage_mailgun:
          class: foo\WebsiteBundle\SwiftMailer\customMailgunTransport
          arguments: ['@mailgun.swift_transport.eventdispatcher','@mailgun.library','testdomain.com']
```

Thought I'd post the solution incase anyone else came up against it.